# How to merge datasets by date category? SAS

Tags: date, merge, sas, dataset

I am new to stack overflow. I am also a beginner in SAS. I have two datasets: one with a list of ID's and medications by date and one with ID's and dates by admission number. I am trying to get a list of medications by ID, organized by admission number in SAS.

I've tried merging by ID number and creating an "admission number" variable by using:

```
 if admission_date-admission_date_1=0 then admission_number="Admission 1"
```

but all values are missing when I do that.

Here's what I have:

[image]

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't post photographs of data.  Just type the data into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like that second data set is useful at all. What you're doing there is creating a enumeration variable which can be accomplished using a BY variable.

```
proc sort data=have; by id admission_date; run;

data want;
set have;
by id admission_date;
if first.id then admission_number=0;
if first.date then admission_number + 1;
run;
```

More details are available on the methods here if needed.
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I realize I was not clear enough in my description of the data. The first table is a list of all admission dates and medications for patients. The second table is a list of admission dates by admission number for patients that had an outcome of interest. I only want a medication list for admission dates with the outcome of interest. For this reason, enumeration will not work because it will create admission numbers for admissions that should not be included. Is there a way to match data by both id and date? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing in your data about outcomes. How is that being filtered? You need to also post your data as text as I'm not going to type it out to work with it. A simple solution doesn't need the actual data but since it's more complicated it would be helpful for you to provide data as text.